# Gatsby trailing slash redirect issue only on deployed version

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, deployment, gatsby

In my Gatsby app, I want the following routes:

- `/branches` - shows stores' branch locations.
- `/branches/:id` - shows information about a particular branch.

To accomplish this, I have the following folder structure:

```
src
   pages
      branches
         index.tsx
```

Inside `index.tsx`, I have:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router } from '@reach/router'

const Comp = (props: { path: any }) => {
    return <pre>{JSON.stringify(props, null, 2)}</pre>
}

export default () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Comp path="/branches" />
            <Comp path="/branches/:id" />
        </Router>
    )
}
```

(The `Comp` component is there just to show the functionality is working.)

In my `gatsby-node.js` file, I have this:

```
// Implement the Gatsby API “onCreatePage”. This is
// called after every page is created.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions
    // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
    // only on the client.
    if (page.path.match(/^\/branches/)) {
        page.matchPath = '/branches/*'
        // Update the page.
        createPage(page)
    }
}
```

So the result is that when I am running `gatsby develop`, everything works as expected. I can visit `/branches` and `/branches/4` and I see what I expect, the `Comp` component displaying some routing information:

```
{
  "path": "/branches",
  "uri": "/branches",
  "location": {
    "pathname": "/branches/",
    "search": "",
    "hash": "",
    "href": "http://localhost:1337/branches/",
    "origin": "http://localhost:1337",
    "protocol": "http:",
    "host": "localhost:1337",
    "hostname": "localhost",
    "port": "1337",
    "state": null,
    "key": "initial"
  }
}
```

However, when running deploying to S3 using `gatsby build && gatsby-plugin-s3 deploy --yes`, I get into a redirect loop:

[image]

What is the issue here and how can I resolve it?

(I have experimented with the `gatsby-plugin-force-trailing-slashes` and `gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes` plugins to no avail)

Comment: I know from hosting on Netlify that there are settings that control how to deal with trailing slashes. The bug should be in the S3 settings.